# Does 'throwback' require an indefinite article?

Tags: british-english, slang, indefinite-articles

Should it be ‘a cheeky little throwback’ or just ‘cheeky little throwback’

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do dictionaries include the indefinite article with phrases with 'throwback' as head, or not? [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/throwback), for instance, gives two example sentences.

Comment: The use of an article is dependent on the context. Both the examples are grammatical noun phrases. Neither is a sentence, or even an utterance, out of context. Therefore it's unclear what is being asked.

Comment: Context needed!!

Comment: (1) *She is a cheeky little throwback.* (2) *"Why you cheeky little throwback!"* One uses an indefinite article and the other does not. Both are grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you have given, an article is required. "He's a cheeky little throwback." Throwback is a noun, and so an article is required. The article would usually be the indefinite article, although in some cases, such as to emphasize uniqueness, the definite article could be used, such as "Isn't he the cheeky little throwback." Although, it would normally be the indefinite article.